# Dynamic SUM or SUMIF Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to get the SUM of the first column IF the next column has data. In this example, the second column has data for the first 6 rows, therefore the sum that I want to get is the sum of the first 6 numbers in column 1. How the second column gets its data is chronological, so there will be no skipped cells.

[image]

Comment: =SUMIF(B:B,"<>",A:A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this formula:
`=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,">0")`

It will sum the numbers in the first column, if the corresponding letters in the second column are greater than zero. Let me know if this does not cover all of your criteria, I'm sure I can help.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! This formula is helpful since the blank cells in column 2 are formulated. If no data, returns blank, otherwise, returns a value.